Filter the property of an array of object in a Datatable Column
I'm new to Primevue, Here is my example:
User object:
User {
      username: 'test',
      email: 'test@junk.com',
      id: 1,
      role: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Admin',
        description: 'Admin user',
      },
      cars: [{
         "id": 1,
         "title": "Subaru BRZ"
         "color": "red"
         }, {
         "id": 2,
         "title": "Lotus Evora GT"
         "color": "red"
         }, {
         "id": 3,
         "title": "Lotus Evora GT"
         "color": "blue"
         }, {
         "id": 1,
         "title": "Subaru BRZ"
         "color": "yellow"
      }]
    }

<DataTable 
    ...
      <Column field="cars" filterField="cars" :showFilterMenu="false" header="Cars">
                        <template #body="{ data }">
                            <div class="flex align-items-center gap-2">
                                <Tag v-for="car in data.cars" :key="name" :value="car.name ?? 'Undefined'" class="me-2 mb-2"></Tag>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                        <template #filter="{ filterModel, filterCallback }">
                            <MultiSelect v-model="filterModel.value" @change="filterCallback()" ..>
                                ...
                            </MultiSelect>
                        </template>
                    </Column>
    </DataTable>

data() {
        return {
            filter: {
                ..
                cars: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS },
            },
...

How to filter datatable like this by color? For example: Show yellow and red cars?
How to custom filter? Any suggestion? I need help about custom filter.

Here is an updated version of your code with result
<DataTable
  v-model:filters="filters"
  :value="carItems"
  paginator
  :rows="10"
  dataKey="id"
  filterDisplay="row"
  :loading="loading"
  :globalFilterFields="['title', 'colorType.color']"
>
  <template #header>
    <div class="flex justify-end">
      <IconField>
        <InputIcon>
          <i class="pi pi-search" />
        </InputIcon>
        <InputText v-model="filters['global'].value" placeholder="Keyword Search" />
      </IconField>
    </div>
  </template>
  <template #empty> No Cars found. </template>
  <template #loading> Loading Cars data. Please wait. </template>
  <Column field="title" header="title" style="min-width: 12rem">
    <template #body="{ data }">
      {{ data.title }}
    </template>
    <template #filter="{ filterModel, filterCallback }">
      <InputText
        v-model="filterModel.value"
        type="text"
        @input="filterCallback()"
        placeholder="Search by Title"
      />
    </template>
  </Column>
  <Column
    header="color"
    filterField="colorType"
    :showFilterMenu="false"
    style="min-width: 12rem"
  >
    <template #body="{ data }">
      <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
        <span>{{ data.colorType.color }}</span>
      </div>
    </template>
    <template #filter="{ filterModel, filterCallback }">
      <MultiSelect
        v-model="filterModel.value"
        @change="filterCallback()"
        :options="colors"
        optionLabel="color"
        placeholder="Any"
        style="min-width: 14rem"
        :maxSelectedLabels="1"
      >
        <template #option="slotProps">
          <div class="flex items-center gap-2">
            <span>{{ slotProps.option.color }}</span>
          </div>
        </template>
      </MultiSelect>
    </template>
  </Column>
</DataTable>

For the Script Part, Here it is
import { onMounted, ref, computed } from 'vue'
import DataTable from 'primevue/datatable'
import Column from 'primevue/column'
import { FilterMatchMode } from '@primevue/core/api'
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext'
import MultiSelect from 'primevue/multiselect'

const filters = ref({
  global: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS },
  title: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.STARTS_WITH },
  colorType: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.IN }
})

const user = ref({
  username: 'test',
  email: 'test@junk.com',
  id: 1,
  role: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Admin',
    description: 'Admin user'
  },
  cars: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Subaru BRZ',
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Lotus Evora GT',
      color: 'red'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Lotus Evora GT',
      color: 'blue'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Subaru BRZ',
      color: 'yellow'
    }
  ]
})

const carItems = computed(() => {
  return user.value.cars.map((car) => {
    return {
      id: car.id,
      title: car.title,
      colorType: {
       color: car.color
     }
   }
 })
})
const colors = ref([]); //an array for the different colors in the car array
const carColorCheck = ref([]); //an array to check for unique colors and to avoid repeating colors.

carItems.value.forEach((car) => {
  const color = car.colorType.color
  if (!carColorCheck.value.includes(color)) {
    carColorCheck.value.push(color)
    colors.value.push({ color })
  }
})

The reason for creating a new map object for the cars is for us to be able create a color object for each car as the filter needed an object and not a string.
You can check the documentation here.
I hope this helps.
